# computing haversine over two lists

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I'm currently trying to compute route distance of (lat/long) coordinates that I have in Geopandas data frame. I'm pretty new to the package, but basically I have several points that make up a route and all I'm trying to do is find the total real distance of the route. I'm able to do so with two fixed points, to which I owe the help to user @steve clark:

```
# Start
lon1 = 41.592181
lat1 = -87.638856
# End
lat2 = -86.754688
lon2 = 41.877575

def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers
    print('Distance from beginning to end of route in km: ',round((c * r), 2),'\n')
```

I get stuck on two things, I'm currently scouring around to see if I can just calculate distance from the Geopandas `point()` object, but in all honesty the examples I find are either not related to my question, or beyond my scope of understanding (at this time).

I'm able to pull both latitude and longitude columns from my gpd into lists but I get stuck applying it over loop

```
LatList = geo_data['latitude'].tolist()
LonList = geo_data['longitude'].tolist()
```

I try and append what I iterate through into a new list and sum the distances, but I end up getting a list with the same value appended 2,850 times. Any help or direction appreciated!

EDIT: As requested, this is the code that fails

```
distance = []

    for i, j in zip(LatList, LonList):

        dlat = i - i+1
        dlon = j - j+1

        a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
        c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
        r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers

        distance.append(round((c * r), 2))

    print(distance)
```

Comment: A good idea would be to include the code failing to work as expected to your question. It's probably a typo or something similar trivial in your code that causes the script to fail to provide what you are after.

Comment: @Claudio added it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the definitions of `i`, `i+1`, `j` and `j+1`, otherwise the loop will not do what you want it to.

```
distance = []

LatLonList = list(zip(LatList, LonList))

    # notice that if you do "for n in len(LatLonList)", the loop will fail in the last element
    for n in len(LatLonList) -1:

        dlat = LatLonList[n][0] - LatLonList[n+1][0]  # this is for i
        dlon = LatLonList[n][1] - LatLonList[n+1][1]  # this is for j

        a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
        c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
        r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers

        distance.append(round((c * r), 2))

    print(distance)
```

Comment: `LatLonList = zip(LatList, LonList)`, does not have Len() since its a generator, I've tried changing back to `for n in zip(LatList, LonList):` which brings me back to square one

Comment: fixed, `pre_LatLonList = map(lambda x,y:(x,y),latlist,lonlist)`
`LatLonList = list(pre_LatLonList)`

Comment: You're right, that part needs a fix, and I'm glad you fond a solution.  There is a simpler solution though:  `list(zip(  ...  ))`

Answer (score 2):

use the data from geopandas reference as an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import Point

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'City': ['Buenos Aires', 'Brasilia', 'Santiago', 'Bogota', 'Caracas'],
     'Country': ['Argentina', 'Brazil', 'Chile', 'Colombia', 'Venezuela'],
     'Latitude': [-34.58, -15.78, -33.45, 4.60, 10.48],
     'Longitude': [-58.66, -47.91, -70.66, -74.08, -66.86]})
df['Coordinates'] = list(zip(df.Longitude, df.Latitude))
df['Coordinates'] = df['Coordinates'].apply(Point)
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='Coordinates')
```

the distance using two points as input can be writen as below:

```py
def haversine(point1, point2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    lon1, lat1 = point1.bounds[0], point1.bounds[1]
    lon2, lat2 = point2.bounds[0], point2.bounds[1]

    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers
    # print('Distance from beginning to end of route in km: ',round((c * r), 2),'\n')
    return c * r
```

and the calculation using `pandas.DataFrame.apply`:

```py
gdf['Coordinates'].apply(lambda x: gdf['Coordinates'].apply(lambda y: haversine(x, y)))
```

EDIT: 
only calculate half of the matrix

```py
gdf[['Coordinates']].apply(lambda x: gdf.loc[:x.name, 'Coordinates'].apply(lambda y: haversine(x['Coordinates'], y)), axis=1)
```

Comment: This is running, however it is taking extremely long, which is making me think something is being passed incorrectly? For `point1, point2` where are those being created, because `point()` is just a tuple in gdf which has no `point1, point2`.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I passed in initial points `point1, point2` however this still is taking very long (20+ min)

Comment: the point() are created in `df['Coordinates'] = df['Coordinates'].apply(Point)`, which transfer the tuple to the Point object.

Comment: it takes long because the algorithm of `haversine` method doesn't change. I've modified the calculation part so that it only calculate only half of the matrix. you can fill the other half symmetrical

Answer (score 0):

Found this code from this [relevant question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41238665/calculating-geographic-distance-between-a-list-of-coordinates-lat-lng) [Calculating geographic distance between a list of coordinates (lat, lng)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41238665/calculating-geographic-distance-between-a-list-of-coordinates-lat-lng),

```
def calculate_distance(positions):
    results = []
    for i in range(1, len(positions)):
        loc1 = positions[i - 1]
        loc2 = positions[i]

        lat1 = loc1[0]
        lng1 = loc1[1]

        lat2 = loc2[0]
        lng2 = loc2[1]

        degreesToRadians = (math.pi / 180)
        latrad1 = lat1 * degreesToRadians
        latrad2 = lat2 * degreesToRadians
        dlat = (lat2 - lat1) * degreesToRadians
        dlng = (lng2 - lng1) * degreesToRadians

        a = math.sin(dlat / 2) * math.sin(dlat / 2) + math.cos(latrad1) * \
        math.cos(latrad2) * math.sin(dlng / 2) * math.sin(dlng / 2)
        c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))
        r = 6371000

        results.append(r * c)

    return (sum(results) / 1000)  # Converting from m to km
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a package for computing Haversine distance
https://pypi.org/project/haversine/
which comes with a numpy version that will speed up computation over lists.